# What did Bruce Eckel mean by the formulation "inside methods of that type" in the term "private"?

Tags: java, theory, definition, access-modifiers

> The private keyword, on the other hand, means that no one can access that element except you, the creator of the type, **inside methods of that type.**

I don’t really understand what’s going on in the highlighted text.

Comment: It means that private members cannot be used outside methods of the type they're declared in.

Comment: Maybe the [official oracle tutorial on access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) clears things up.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a code illustration will help

```
public MyClass {
    private int someField = 1;

    public boolean isFieldZero() {
        return someField == 0;
    }
}

public MyOtherClass {
    public void test() {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(c.someField);  // <<< ERROR
    }
}
```

"I" wrote the type `MyClass`.  "I" can access the `private` field `someField` inside the method `isFieldZero` ... or any other method *of that type* that "I" choose to write.  "Nobody else" can.  And neither can "my" second class `MyOtherClass`.

OK so the quoted text is a bit loose in the way that it is conflating the code (`MyClass`) with the code's author<sup>1</sup>(me).  That is potentially misleading, and perhaps it was what is confusing you.  Some textbook authors use that style of writing to try to *engage with* the readers of their books.   It shouldn't be taken literally.

In reality, the Java compiler is going to allow and restrict access by **Java code** not people.

---

<sup>1 - ... or authors, considering that a given class may be modified by many people over the time that the application, etc containing the class is maintained.</sup>

Comment: Additional info: aside from *methods* `private` fields can also be accessed from initialization blocks/constructors of class which declared it and from outer/nested classes.